# adjacency matrix

Tags: java, c++, graph

Given an adjacency matrix of a graph and a positive integer n find the number of path of length n between two vertices, I don't know how to convert to programming?

Comment: This is very homeworky, and much more mathy than programmy

Comment: It is still valid question for this place and clearly stated. No reason for downvote and close.

Comment: You say you're having trouble "coverting to programming."  Can you give us what you *have* (in other words, what you're trying to convert *from*, even if it's pseudocode or an english description of the algorithm) and where you're getting stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Take A^n then read the appropriate entry.

If you want it more efficient for single vertices, do a random walker starting at first vertex for n iterations.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is homework, so here's a hint.  If you were given a pencil and paper, and a small adjacency matrix, how would *you* count the number of paths?

Answer (score 0):

This is my coding, but I do not know how to find the number of path of length between two vertices.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#define TRUE 1
#define FALSE 0

void main()
{
   int x;            
   int y;
   int n;
   int l;
   int a;
   int b;
   int length;
   char vertex='a';
   int num[50][50];

   printf("enter the number of vertices : ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   //int num[n][n];

   for(x=0;x<n;x++)
   {
    for(y=0;y<n;y++)
      {
        printf("[%c,%c] : ",vertex+x,vertex+y);
         scanf("%d",&num[x][y]);
       }
   }

        printf("\n");

        printf("Adjacency matrix :\n");
        for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<n;y++)

                printf("%d\t",num[x][y]);
                printf("\n");

            }

         printf("Enter a positive integer for length: ");
         scanf("%d",&length);

         length=sqrt(length);

         printf("Multiplication matrix :\n");
      for(l=0;l<=length;l++)
      {
        for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<n;y++)

                num[x][y]=(num[x][y])*(num[y][x]);
               num[x][y]= num[x][y]+ num[y][x];

            }
       }


        printf("\n");

        for(x=0;x<n;x++)
        {
            for(y=0;y<n;y++)

                printf("%d\t",num[x][y]);
                printf("\n");

            }

         printf("\nPlease insert your starting point: ");
         scanf("%d",&a);
         printf("\nPlease insert your ending point: ");
         scanf("%d",&b);

         a=x-1;
         b=y-1;

         //printf("\nThe number of path from %d to %d: %d",a,b,num[a][b]);
         printf("\nThe number of path from %d to %d: %d",a,b,num[a][b]);

   getch();
   //return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using Dijkstra's shortest path algorithm (DSPA)? Let the cost of each arc in the network be 1. Use DSPA to find the distance between two distinct vertices. If the length is n, you have found a path of interest. Loop over all pairs of vertices.